# How to open a Java file by a class name from command line?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Is it possible to open a Java source file in IntelliJ Idea from command line by its class name (simple or qualified) as part of already opened project?

When `idea64.exe --help` is run, following dialog pops up:

[image: Idea command line options popup]

It doesn't mention any option for opening by a class name.

Comment: Nope. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-the-ide-features-from-command-line.html#arguments Absolute path only

Comment: No, you may try the [Searching Everywhere](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/searching-everywhere.html) in IDEA for your use case. @Michael Relative path should be ok here too (e.g. `idea64.exe sample.txt`).

Comment: @LJreplica He specifically wants from the command line so linking to a feature that's unrelated to the command line is not helpful